# Computing correlation coefficient in linear regression

Tags: regression, self-study

I'm working with a linear regression model given by the following formula
$$y = \beta_1x + \beta_0 + \epsilon.$$

I am to prove that the correlation coefficient between $\hat{y}$ and $\epsilon$ is equal to zero if the model is correct.

Basically this problem comes down to prove that $Cov(\hat{y}, \epsilon) = 0$. I'm a bit stuck here. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Please add the self-study tag, read its wiki, and post your progress on showing $Cov(\hat{y}, \epsilon)$.

Comment: I think you mean the covariance with $\hat\epsilon$, otherwise this would not be true.

Comment: To make any progress, you will need either some very strong way to characterize $\hat y$ or an explicit formula for it.  One characterization, called the "Normal Equations," includes this assertion.  Since any formula for $\hat y$ solves the Normal Equations, that would work too.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=regression+%22normal+equations%22+-logistic+-ridge+score%3A1 and  https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=regression+%22normal+equation%22+-logistic+-ridge+score%3A1 for more.